# Restricting User From Going Over 100 in Textfield

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

How do I restrict users from going over 100 in a textfield in Actionscript 3?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
function _handleTextChanges(evt:Event):void{

     var target:TextInput = evt.currentTarget as TextInput;
     if(!target) return;
     if(parseInt(target.text) > 100){
         target.text = "100";
     }
     if(parseInt(target.text) < 0){
         Alert.show("You can't enter a number smaller than 0");
         target.text = "0";
     }

}
```

Comment: And what if there would be an "a" in the textfield? Exception?

Comment: You can use try and catch for that. Try {parseInt (target.text);}catch(E exception){target.text="";}

Comment: you can also use [`restrict`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#restrict) for that

Answer (score 0):

I think what OP meant is the text-length restriction. If it's the case, use [`maxChars`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#maxChars).